# Problema de índice fuera de intervalo al ocultar columna de GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Tengo un `Gridview` con los datos de un carrito y quiero ocultar la primera columna, el cual es el código de artículo.

Intenté con:

`gvCarrito.Columns.RemoveAt(0)`

`gvCarrito.Columns[0].Visible = false;`

Y ninguna funciona, me muestra el siguiente error:

> El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección.

La grilla lo lleno y muestro:

```
gvCarrito.DataSource = (List<Carrito>)Session["carrito"];
gvCarrito.DataBind();   
gvCarrito.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

Igualmente, probé cambiando la verificacion al final y nada..

**Actualización:**

Ejecuto el siguiente código y no oculta la columna.

```
gvCarrito.DataSource = (List<Carrito>)Session["carrito"];
gvCarrito.DataBind();
if (gvCarrito.Columns.Count > 0)
{
    gvCarrito.Columns[0].Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: El error lo tienes en que código? cellclick o cellcontentclick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección.

El mismo mensaje de error te indica el problema. Estas evaluando el **índice** de valor **0**, como no es negativo debe ser inferior al tamaño de la colección.

Por tal motivo, antes de ejecutar dicho código tienes que evaluar que al menos dicho `GridView` tenga columnas.

```
if (gvCarrito.Columns.Count > 0){
  gvCarrito.Columns[0].Visible = false;
}
```

**Actualización:**

Si las columnas de tu grilla se están autogenerando (propiedad `AutoGenerateColumns` en `true`, por defecto tiene ese valor) no se puede realizar de esa manera, solo se podría oculta en el evento [`RowDataBound`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
protected void gvCarrito_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
}
```

**Recomendación**

> Por lo general no se autogenera las columnas, se define y en base a eso se puede realizar modificaciones a la columna de forma directa. Por ejemplo: visibilidad, formato, longitud, etc...

Comment: El grid no está vacio porque me muestra los datos que necesito.. Se me hace raro. Igualmente hice la verificacion que me indicas y la pasa de largo, pero en la pagina me muestra los datos..

Comment: @YamilaMarucci con la verificación, ¿ya no te muestra el error?

Comment: Claro, no muestra el error pero tampoco oculta la columna..

Comment: @YamilaMarucci favor de modificar tu pregunta y agregar las líneas de código donde agregas y ocultas la columna. Si no arroja error es que dicha grilla no tiene todavía columnas cuando lo quieres ocultar. :)

Comment: lo hice de la forma que me indicas, y tampoco me oculta la columna..

Comment: Aguanta, @YamilaMarucci ¿Indicaste columnas en el `.ASPX` o estás dejando que se autogeneren?

Comment: Dejo que se autogeneren.. Por eso no me deja?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54106/discussion-between-davlio-and-yamila-marucci).

Answer (score 0):

Con respeto tu pregunta, es necesario agregar el numero de columna que deseas y agregas la propiedad true or false.

this.ClienteDataGridView.Columns[0].Visible = false;

Espero y te haya ayudado.

Comment: Es lo que hice y me tira ese error.. Hay alguna otra forma de ocultar una columna?

Comment: Mhhh, ok intenta con la propiedad width, te anexo un ejemplo (no lo he probrado) dataGrid1.Tabla[0].GridColumn[0].Width = 0, te anexo tambien una liga donde la extraje: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/79zaexf1(v=vs.110).aspx, por que la unicá forma que yo he intentado es con la propiedad false.

Answer (score 0):

No se puede ocultar la columna, por que aún no existen columnas.

Primero carga tu DataGrid y despues establece 
gvCarrito.Columns[0].Visible = false;

Comment: Exactamente así lo hice.. Y nada, sigue sin funcar..